# Change currency symbol position from left to right in RTL theme

Tags: magento2, currency, currency-symbol

I have tried to change currency position using below mentioned observer code its working on English website that list LTR but its not working on Arabic website that is RTL.

app/code/Vendor/Moduele/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="vendor_module_change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Changecurrencyposition" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Changecurrencyposition.php

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    

class Changecurrencyposition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);  
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

What i observed is there is tag `&rlm;` coming between currency symbol and amount `AED&rlm;10.00` and when i removing this `&rlm;` tag by inspect element it working but its not working by code. Your help is highly appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Currency" />

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Currency.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
{
    public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
    {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="change_currency_position" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\ChangeCurrencyPosition" />
    </event>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**ChangeCurrencyPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCurrencyPosition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);
        //$currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution worked for me, thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 0):

Please change $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);  to $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    

class Changecurrencyposition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);  
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's I know I am able to change right but what I said is its not working for Arabic or RTL site. Also I have posted my observation why its not working.